# Can't access namespaces from Nuget Package

Tags: c#, namespaces, nuget-package

I have an Identity Server 3 Project where I need to install a couple of custom Nuget Packages, that comes from a private Nuget Package repository in my company. This Nuget is installed and running in many other web projects so it is most likely not the problem.

When I install the package on Identity Server Project, logs say everything was fine and the package was successfully installed. It is listed on Project References. But when I try to access it anywhere on Identity Server Project, it just isn't accessible. I can't set up an using reference, neither call any methods by using it's full namespace (InstalledNuget.Services.Example). Visual Studio's intellisense returns "The type or namespace name does not exist in namespace 'company' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

While investigating the issue, I found out that it is listed on Project References, but not on Object Browser.

I tried:

- reinstalling the package;
- restarting Visual Studio;
- Deleting the packages folder and let the program restore then again;

I have been to several posts here and other websites but did not find a problem matches this one. Any hints?

Comment: Namespaces are hierarchical and must have all parents defined.  So when you have System.Net.Socket you have three namespaces 1) System 2) Net 3) Socket  and each must have one definition.  You company namespace is either missing or under the wrong parent.

Comment: @jdweng Both are under the same namespace called "Company". For example, the project I'm working on is called "Company.Login", and the Nuget is called "Company.Parameters". That's how we usually do.

Comment: When you create new project you will see : namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ Here is the namespace} Your code is missing a similar definition for Company.  Or the error is occurring in a different module and you need to add the using statement for the namespace

Comment: This may occur if your project targets a .NET version which is not supported by the nuget package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was some visual bug on Visual Studio. I accidentally clicked on run, and it run successfully, with errors still on the screen. It ignored then completely.

Then I manually removed "bin" and "obj" folders and everything returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue. For me it was accidentally using **internal** (visibility only within assembly) instead of **public** (visibility between assemblies) on my class in my nuget (classLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried to reinstall package, clean solution, rebuild solution, delete obj and bin folders.
What solved it in the end was restarting Visual Studio...